# Variable (tab name) not working when I need fill cell

Tags: python, tabs, openpyxl

I have a problem, unfortunatelly this combination is not working (empty cells in "4" tab as result below code).
Do you know whats a problem?
I need get into tab by variable not fixed name.

```
book.create_sheet("4")
tab_4 = book.get_sheet_by_name('4')
ktora = 4
ktora_zakladka = "tab_" + str(ktora)
ktora_zakladka +".cell(column=" + str(numerkolumny) +", row=" + str(wiersz_zakladka4) +", value=" + 
str(assets3[w2]) + ").font = style_blad"
```

When I go through below everything is fine:

```
tab_4.cell(column=numerkolumny, row=wiersz_zakladka4, value=assets3[w2]).font=style_blad
```

Comment: It looks to me like you could do with a tutorial in Python. The following is probably all you need to do: `ws = book["tab_4"]; cell = ws.cell(row=wiersz_zakladka4, column=numerkolumny); cell.font =Font(bold=True)`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `+=` to append to a string. Use `exec` to run dynamic code.

Try this code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
book = Workbook()

numerkolumny = wiersz_zakladka4 = 9
w2 = 0
assets3 = [123]

book.create_sheet("4")
tab_4 = book.get_sheet_by_name('4')
ktora = 4
ktora_zakladka = "tab_" + str(ktora)
ktora_zakladka += ".cell(column=" + str(numerkolumny) +", row=" + str(wiersz_zakladka4) +", value=" + \
str(assets3[w2]) + ").font = 'style_blad'"

exec(ktora_zakladka)  # run command, write to excel file

book.save('tab4.xlsx')
```

Comment: There is no need to use `exec` at all.